# Freemarker macros with few nested elements

Tags: macros, freemarker

how can I have few different **#nested** elements in macros?

Answer (score 29):

You cant have different **#nested** elements in a macro, every usage of it will output the same text.

If you goal it to have multiple variable sections in your macro, you can use the **#assign** element.

Example of a page **#macro** allowing to define the body, header and footer content :

```
<#macro pageTemplate header="" footer="">
    ${header}
    <#nested >
    ${footer}
</#macro>
```

You can then define each section using the **#assign** element (but admittedly having multiple named **#nested** element would be better).

```
<#assign headerContent>
     This is the header.
</#assign>
<#assign footerContent>
     This is the footer.
</#assign>
<@pageTemplate header=headerContent footer=footerContent>
     This is the nested content.
</@pageTemplate>
```

The resulting output will be :

```
This is the header.
This is the nested content.
This is the footer.
```

Comment: this solution works great as long as you don't have [auto-escaping](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html) on, which is actually a good idea. i usually do `${footer?no_esc}` to disable escaping if `footer` is expected to contain markup.